# VB.NET Disable past date in monthcalendar

Tags: vb.net, monthcalendar

How can i disable the past date and only enable 3 dates from today's date in monthcalendar using vb.net? I couldn't find the dayrender event.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can makeuse of MinDate and MaxDate property of the 
MonthCalendar control to achieve your need,

**CODE:**

```
MonthCalTest.MinDate = New DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day)
MonthCalTest.MaxDate = MonthCalTest.MinDate.AddDays(3)
```

[MINDATE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.monthcalendar.mindate%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) - [MAXDATE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/system.windows.forms.monthcalendar.maxdate%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks. 

But now, i want to show the disabled date but not hide it. How can i do this?